# Is there a Scalding source I can use for lzo-compressed binary data?

Tags: hadoop, protocol-buffers, thrift, scalding, lzo

I am writing serialized Thrift records to a file using [Elephant Bird's](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird) splittable LZO compression. To achieve this I am using their `ThriftBlockWriter` class. My Scalding job then uses the [FixedPathLzoThrift](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/7be27766e0c87675d1082cd70379a2c4c3f863c1/scalding-commons/src/main/scala/com/twitter/scalding/commons/source/FixedPathSources.scala) source to process the records. This all works fine. The problem is that I am limited to records of a single Thrift class.

I want to start using `RawBlockWriter` instead of `ThriftBlockWriter[MyThriftClass]`. So instead of LZO-compressed Thrift records, my input will be LZO-compressed raw byte arrays. My question is: what should I use instead of `FixedPathLzoThrift[MyThriftClass]`?

Explanation of "protocol-buffers" tag: Elephant Bird uses a Protocol Buffers `SerializedBlock` class to wrap the raw input, as seen [here](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird/blob/94aa4a7dd250457bf231fdac6ab5e12a987263c0/core/src/main/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/mapreduce/io/SerializedBlock.java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a `FixedPathLzoRaw` class to use in place of `FixedPathLzoThrift` :

```
case class FixedPathLzoRaw(path: String*) extends FixedPathSource(path: _*) with LzoRaw

// Corresponds to LzoThrift trait
trait LzoRaw extends LocalTapSource with SingleMappable[Array[Byte]] with TypedSink[Array[Byte]] {
  override def setter[U <: Array[Byte]] = TupleSetter.asSubSetter[Array[Byte], U](TupleSetter.singleSetter[Array[Byte]])
  override def hdfsScheme = HadoopSchemeInstance((new LzoByteArrayScheme()).asInstanceOf[Scheme[_, _, _, _, _]])
}
```